# For undirected graph, why memory requirement for adjacency list representation is θ(V+E) and not θ(V+2E) ?

Tags: graph, adjacency-list

In case of undirected graph, since there are 2E edges in the adjacency list representation then why the memory requirement is same as that for directed graph?

Comment: You only need to store each edge once. Say an edge is `i, j` with `i < j`. You don't also need to store `j, i`.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, i guess this is not the answer, because the edge is stored in both lists of each vertices, 
i guess the answer is the 2 is subsumed if E is large enough

Answer (score 1):

Theta(V+E) = Theta(V+2E) since 2 is a constant and makes no difference in [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: It doesn't make a difference in big O but what about theta since theta is a tighter bound?

Comment: Look at the definition. Theta(V+E) means it is in Big-O(V+E) and in Omega(V+E). So for a given but fixed n0 and a constant it is in Big-O, in our case that constant is 2. For another constant, let it be 1, it is in Omega.